# How to download latest code from serena dimension on every new build trigger by jenkins

Tags: jenkins, serena

I am using Serena Dimensions for code management, and Jenkins to build the war/ear file. However, I am not able to download the latest code on every new build trigger by Jenkins.

Also, I am able to connect Serena Dimensions to Jenkins.

Comment: Please consider adding any error message or log that might help others to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the job configuration, in Source Code Management section, provide the Dimension project & folder names. In the advanced section, select the "Use update" option. This will take the updated code from Dimension on every build.